# C# Combobox and numericupdown calculation

Tags: c#, combobox

```
 private void submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (fishingrodcomboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        fishingrodcomboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
        decimal two = 18m;
        decimal price = two * fishingrodnumericUpDown.Value;
        totalfishingrodtextBox.Text = price.ToString("C");
    }
    else
    {
           //Do something
    }
}
```

Textbox doesnt display the amount and how i do code it such that when i select something from the combo box i can each a different value?

Comment: Search in google how to debug in C#. This will fix your problem and prevent you from problems like this in the future !